# Is there a function that is called when you visit a view in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, detailview

Is there a function that is called when a user visits a view (specifically a `DetailView`) in django. I am trying to count the number of views a particular page has (like `StackOverflow`), and I want to know if there is a function that I can utilise.

If this is useful, here is the `DetailView`:

```
class DetailQuestionView(DetailView):
   model = Question
   template_name = 'questions/questions-part/question-detail.html'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all the generic class based views the `dispatch` method is the entry point of the view logic, i.e. if the view is used `dispatch` will be called. Also the HTTP method in lowercase i.e. `get`, `post` methods are also called depending on the requests method. Therefore you can override either of these two to suit your needs:

```
class DetailQuestionView(DetailView):
   model = Question
   template_name = 'questions/questions-part/question-detail.html'
   
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       # Your code
       return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: yes thanks! And for anyone who will visit this question, as Abdul said, use the lowercase get method.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, you can use the get method of the DetailView.